# Update JList in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have created a `JFrame` in Eclipse, and also placed a `JList` in the frame using the `Swing` design option. Eclipse puts the list in a `JPanel`. Next to the list, there are a few text `fields(ID, name, etc.)`. Once the user fills the fields, and clicks 'Add', the information gets stored in a SQLite JDBC table. However, when the user clicks add, I also want the `JList` to update itself and display the new record in the list. The list only refreshes only when I restart the program. I have tried to `revalidate()` and repaint the panel created by Eclipse after the record is added to the database, as well as tried to `revalidate()` and repaint the list.

Comment: Ther `ListModel`  has to be updated with the new values .

Answer (score 3):

Register and Listener implementation . Try this code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    private JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
    private int counter = 1;

    public MyFrame() {
        setTitle("Test Updates");

        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        add(tabs, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(list);
        tabs.add("Selections", panel);

        panel = new JPanel();
        button.addActionListener(this);
        panel.add(button);
        tabs.add("Options", panel);

        pack();
    }

    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
        if (button.equals(event.getSource())) {
            listModel.addElement("Item " + counter++);
        }
    }

    /* Test it! */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            @Override public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        });

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the "code snippet" tags. Not that the comments are for JavaScript which is not Java. Just use the "{}" button to mark Java code.